# How to Prevent CM13 Calling by Itself?

Tags: cyanogenmod, security, privacy

I noticed today that my Samsung Galaxy S4 with CM13 (unofficial [Kyasu's](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s4/i9506-develop/rom-cyanogenmod-13-0-12-1-unofficial-t3264134) ROM) called two my contacts itself; those contacts were those which I keep in my blacklist; which was also why I had react to the incident. 
I have a passlock in my phone so calling itself is not possible without a break into my system. 
This implies me that my ROM was cracked, and used for own targets. 
This is the second time, I notice that my phone calls itself; first time, it called my favorite contact one week ago; in the other end, my friend heard only machine/random noise. 
Therefore, I would like to add additional measures to control the security/privacy of my phone.

---

How can you prevent your phone calling itself?

Comment: Android devices don't make calls by themselves... if you had the phone in pocket and accidentally "butt dialed" someone, set a lockscreen password or pattern to prevent it from happening.

Comment: @acejavelin No. I have a passlock in my phone. It is not possible. It implies me that my phone was hacked by using the security wholes existing in kuysu's unofficial ROM.

Comment: Don't use unofficial builds of unstable ROMs?

Comment: @eldarerathis Yes, I understand it now. I would still have some extra protective features even in official unstable builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out more stable ROM. It was not the official one which has noise artifacts, for instance. 
I found some patches made by Temasek/arter97 [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s4/i9506-develop/rom-temasek-s-unofficial-cyanogenmod-12-t3082164) at points (8) and (9). Using them solves the artifact noise problem, which occurs in the official CM13 and kyasu's ROM. I also switched to Temasek ROM which seems to be one of the most used unofficial ROMs. It is the most stable ROM that I have found for the device. It also supports updates directly in the software.